# I can't generate sitemap.xml on my nextjs 14 app because of webpack errors

Tags: next.js, dynamic, frontend, next.js13

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js?page=%2Fsitemap.xml%2Fsitemap.xml%2Froute&isDynamic=1!./app/sitemap.xml/sitemap.tsx?__next_metadata_route__
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:62)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
|   if (typeof handler !== 'function') {
>     throw new Error('Default export is missing in "D:\\Sabbir's Home\\faw-app\\app\\sitemap.xml\\sitemap.tsx"')
|   }
|

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js?page=%2Fsitemap.xml%2Fsitemap.xml%2Froute&isDynamic=1!./app/sitemap.xml/sitemap.tsx?__next_metadata_route__


> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've seen some solutions and they told to check the following things:

- Check Node.js and npm versions
- Update TypeScript
- Review loader documentation
- Temporarily remove loaders
- Check for common pitfalls
- Upgrade Next.js
- Update other dependencies

I've checked everything from my end and all of them are fine. But still I am suffering from this error.

Moreover, when I remove the sitemap.tsx file from the project then everything is working fine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the name of your sitemap file?